# How to use WebSecurity.createUserAndAccount with custom field

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a register model with these fields

```
public class Register
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "The Mobile Number should be atleast 11 characters long")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
     }
```

How do I add these fields in my UserProfile table with  these statement
     WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`CreateUserAndAccount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount(v=vs.111).aspx) method taking an anonymous object as third parameter allowing you to pass arbitrary custom fields associated to the user account:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
    userName: model.UserName, 
    password: model.Password,
    propertyValues: new 
    {
        Email = model.Email,
        MobileNo = model.MobileNo,
    },
    requireConfirmationToken: false
);
```